# Problem with Slerp Rotation Coroutine Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that I want to rotate 90 degree smoothly when a condition is checked.

The problem I have is that the rotation work fine and smooth, but the object didn't reach the final rotation (90 degree), it reach 81 degree and it stops! what's wrong in my code?

**Script:**

```
void Update() {
    if (Objects.Length == 0)
    {
        if (!Rotated)
        {
            StartCoroutine(RotateMe(Vector3.up * 90, 1f));
            Rotated = true;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator RotateMe(Vector3 byAngles, float inTime)
{
    var fromAnglePlat = Platform.transform.rotation;
    var toAnglePlat = Quaternion.Euler(Platform.transform.eulerAngles + byAngles);

    for (var t = 0f; t < 1; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime)
    {
            Platform.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(fromAnglePlat, toAnglePlat, t);

            yield return null;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `t < 1`

`t` will never equal 1, ergo, the final rotation (to 90 degrees) will not be performed.

You should add `Platform.transform.rotation = toAnglePlat` after the loop to insure that the exact desired rotation is the final one before the coroutine terminates (this will always be true, whereas `t <= 1` will still fail, because `0.995` is less than 1, but adding `0.02` from delta time would be greater than 1).

Comment: as alternative you could e.g. use `t += Mathf.Min(Time.deltaTime, inTime - t) / inTime` so there won't be overshooting

Answer (score 1):

When you're dealing with slerp and lerp, it's important to remember that the 't' parameter is a percentage (in decimal form, so 0 - 1, not 0 - 100), not a linear increase. You're missing an important variable, which is the duration you want your slerp to last. The formula you'd typically use to get your 't' parameter is t = timeSinceStart / duration.